# Scala String split bizareness

Tags: string, scala, split

I wrote this code

```
val line = "Aaa Bbb Ccc"
line.split(" ")
```

which produces the following output as expected:

```
res31: Array[String] = Array(Aaa, Bbb, Ccc)
```

I change the code *slightly*:

```
val line = "Aaa|Bbb|Ccc"
line.split("|")
```

And now I don't understand the output:

```
res30: Array[String] = Array("", A, a, a, |, B, b, b, |, C, c, c)
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: I'm no expert with Scala, so I'll leave it to someone to provide an answer that contains a proper solution and relevant links to the documentation, but it's probably because `String.split(String)` takes a regex. Maybe try `line.split("\\|")` or `line.split('|')`?

Comment: FTR this is not limited to Scala, it also happens in Java of course since String.split comes from Java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a string representing the regex to split on - "|" is a regex for the empty string or another empty string, so it splits between every character. You need to escape the `|`:

```
line.split("\\|")
```

alternatively you can use the overload which takes a `Char` parameter to split on (defined in `StringOps`):

```
line.split('|')
```

Answer (score 8):

Pipe "|" is a regex character that means either of two options. In that case either empty or empty.

Try escaping it to use it as a character:

```
val line = "Aaa|Bbb|Ccc"
line.split("\\|")

res0: Array[String] = Array(Aaa, Bbb, Ccc)
```